# How do I set the timezone from the CLI on Ubuntu 10.04 server?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, time, time-zone

I'm currently on an Ubuntu 10.04 server with CLI access only.  The timezone is set to PDT but I want to set it to EDT.  How can I achieve that from the CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command `sudo tzselect` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`